# Tweepy api.get_status().in_reply_to_status_id_str returns None

Tags: python, api, tweepy

No matter what tweet I use when I call `myTweet.text` it returns the text for the tweet I want but when I call `myTweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str` it returns `None` even if there are replies to the tweet.

Am I using it wrong? This is the only way I can find online of how to get the replies to a tweet. Thank you in advance for your help, the code:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

myTweet = api.get_status('id')
print(myTweet)

print(myTweet.text)
print('---', myTweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in_reply_to_status_id_str` attribute will contain the string representation of the original Tweet’s ID if the represented Tweet is a reply. See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.

Twitter's API does not have a direct method/endpoint to retrieve replies to a specific Tweet.
Instead, you'll have to use the search APIs and filter the results manually.

Comment: oh that's very inefficient but I understand how to do it thank you very much for the information, I quickly hit the rate limit doing so but it doesn't show on my twitter dashboard that I've used any requests at all, any clue why this might be? Thank you for all the help btw, sorry I'm new to twitters api

Comment: The dashboard will show your subscriptions. If you're using the standard search API, that's generally available and won't be there.